# different answers for same division

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, fake-proofs

I recently came across an easy question which stumped me . It is as follows:

simplify the following expression

a/b/c/d/e/f .

My approach:
for a/b/c/d it's easy to see as dividing a fraction (a/b) by another fraction (c/d) and hence we get answer as ad/bc

However here if we take first fraction as (a/b/c/d) and second fraction as (e/f) the 
then first fraction simplifies to (ad/bc) and hence [ad/bc]/(e/f) = (adf/bce)

Now if we take first fraction as (a/b) and second fraction as 
(c/d/e/f) then the second fraction simplifies to (cf/de) 
and hence (a/b)/[cf/de] = (ade/bcf)

notice that e and f are interchanged in the two answers .so how can we tackle this anomaly?

Comment: The symbol $a/b/c/d/e/f$ does not have  a meaning. To give it a proper meaning you have to add brackets.

Comment: does it mean that seven divided by six divided by five divided by four divided by three divided by two doesn't really have a meaning?

Comment: It has a meaning only then you specify the order in which divisions are to be  carried out.

Comment: It is needlessly muddled notation intended to create confusion. "Problems" like this and other order of operations "gotcha puzzles" are not good math questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, from a purely mathematical viewpoint the expression is ambiguous. However, in most programming languages division is treated as left-associative, so that $a/b/c/d/e/f$ is simplified to $\frac a{bcdef}$.